# How to avoid calling 'onCreated()' method of near tabs when i switch to some tabs?

Tags: android, eclipse, tabs, fragmentpageradapter

i'm working on application in eclipse that have 5 tab and i have spent much time for that but now i have a big problem :

> when one of tabs is activated the next tab and prev tab is loading too
>   and onCreated() method is called but i don't need that i need just
>   calling onCreated() method when switching to tabs
>   [image]

### This is my project files

**mainActivity.java**

```
package info.androidhive.tabsswipe;
import info.androidhive.tabsswipe.adapter.TabsPagerAdapter;
import ir.zinoo.mankan.R;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;


public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {


    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Initilization

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());



        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

         //Adding Tabs
        for (String tab_name : tabs) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setTabListener(this));
        }
        actionBar.setStackedBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#333333")));
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#333333")));

        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // on changing the page
                // make respected tab selected
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {


    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // on tab selected
        // show respected fragment view
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**tabPagerAdapter.java class**

```
package info.androidhive.tabsswipe.adapter;

import info.androidhive.tabsswipe.BmiFragment;
import info.androidhive.tabsswipe.CaloriFragment;
import info.androidhive.tabsswipe.FatFragment;
import info.androidhive.tabsswipe.KamarFragment;
import info.androidhive.tabsswipe.OstokhanFragment;
import info.androidhive.tabsswipe.OtherFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {

        switch (index) {
        case 0:
            // Top Rated fragment activity
            return new BmiFragment();
        case 1:
            // Games fragment activity
            return new CaloriFragment();
        case 2:
            // Movies fragment activity
            return new KamarFragment();
        case 3:
            // Movies fragment activity
            return new OstokhanFragment();
        case 4:
            // Movies fragment activity
            return new FatFragment();
        case 5:
            // Movies fragment activity
            return new OtherFragment();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
         //get item count - equal to number of tabs
        return 6;
    }

}
```

### **Now My question is How to avoid calling on created method of other tabs when in switch to special tab?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. You can set your number of "pre-cache" tabs in your View Pager

```
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
```

But the minimum number to load is one back and forward, the equivalent:

```
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);
```

In order to be able to swipe.

Comment: tanks so mach its ture
how can i contact with you in facebook or google+ i have some problem